# how do I send parameters as a string

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to do the following:

```
String dbURL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:DB,USERNAME,PASSWORD";
//Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(dbURL);
```

conn.createStatment is expecting 3 parameters, not just 1 string so i get an error. is it possible to have them all in one string and pass it? I know it's not the right way to go about this particular problem but i'm asking for future reference as well.

Edit: my mistake. i mean

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL)
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You pass SQL to the `createStatement` method, not a JDBC URL. You would've used the URL to get the `Connection` object.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PreparedStatement` instead. It is supposed to get SQL query as a parameter. Your connection string is supposed to be passed to [`DriverManager.getConnection()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String%29) method

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, what you are doing just won't work. Use this:

```
String dbURL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:DB,USERNAME,PASSWORD";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("your SQL");
```

The first line is your database URL.

The second line will get the actual connection using the db URL.

The third line will let you get the prepared statement from your connection.

This pattern is widely used, so you should use it too (unless you're in Java EE, where obtaining db connections works a bit differently).

Answer (score 0):

Working with JDBC requires several steps. Usually they are:

1. Create a connection;
2. Create a statement (or prepared statement);
3. Execute the statement;
4. Process the results;
5. Close the resources (result set, statement, connection).

I have a feeling you're not sure about JDBC basics. Take a look at the [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Comment: Yes, I did. The question is extremely confusing, since it's talking about `conn.createStatement` and its 3 parameters, and then about `DriverManager.getConnection`. You can edit the question to make it clearer.